# Can I select ng-content within ng-container (or otherwise)?

Tags: angular, ng-content

I have a component with an `ng-content` that selects a specific element but when I wrap the element in an `ng-container`, it does not render.

I need the select of the `ng-content` to be specific so that I can exclude rendering of other elements so I can keep the code clean and as intended.

Component:

```html
<ng-content select="input"></ng-content>
```

Content:

```html
<input id="1" />
<input id="2" />
<ng-container *ngIf="condition"> <!-- Condition has a thruthy value -->
    <input [id]="item + 2" *ngFor="let item of [1, 2, 3, 4]" />
</ng-container>
```

Output

```html
<input id="1" />
<input id="2" />
```

Expected output

```html
<input id="1" />
<input id="2" />
<input id="3" />
<input id="4" />
<input id="5" />
<input id="6" />
```

I tried both with `ng-container` and `ng-template` but neither seems to work.

Does anyone have an idea how to resolve this or if it even is possible?

Comment: What is `*ngIf="condition"`; do the inputs appear if you remove that?

Comment: Sorry, this was just pseudo code. I have a condition that I know for sure to be true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accomplish this with the `ngProjectAs` attribute

```
<ng-container ngProjectAs="input" *ngIf="true"> <!-- Condition has a thruthy value -->
  <input [id]="item + 2" *ngFor="let item of [1, 2, 3, 4]" />
</ng-container>
```

```
<ng-content select="input"></ng-content>
```

Comment: Thanks! This makes the content in `ng-container` render, unfortunately it also renders elements other than `input` which is something I want to prevent.

Content
```html
<div>this should not render</div>
<input id="1" />
```

Comment: It feels a bit hacky and I can still add content other than `input` inside the `ng-container` but for my use case it works great! thank you for your help

Comment: did you change `[select]="'input'"` into `select="input"`?

Comment: I did, but since the `ng-container` is now projected as `input`, it is rendered. The content of the projected input is not checked by the `select` of the `ng-content`, which makes sense.